# how can i reduce memory consumption during prediction with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, memory-management

I have trained a SRGAN model using tensorflow. But during predictions this model takes a lot of memory(RAM) specially for larger images. How can I reduce the memory consumed during prediction?

Answer (score 0):

Try to divide the image into blocks, process and then merge.